# Titanium iOS Module

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am trying to develop an iOS module for where I have to create a UIView but it is giving me

`[ERROR] Script Error = invalid method (createView) passed to ComTestModule at app.js`

I have followed this link
[iOS_Module_Development_Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look here

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules

Specific example is here
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/moddevguide/mobile/ios/example/demos/viewproxyDemo.js